# A question about infimum and supremum.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f,g : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1]$ two functions. My question is whether or not we have that

$$|\inf_{x} f(x) - \inf_{x} g(x)|\leq \sup_{x} |f(x) - g(x)|$$.

If it is not true in general, what are the cases that it is true?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the following possible proof: $sup_{x}|f(x) - g(x)|\geq |sup_{x} f(x) - g(x)| = |\sup_{x}f(x) - \inf_{x}g(x)|$. On the other hand, we also have that $\sup_{x}|f(x) - g(x)| = \sup_{x}|g(x) - f(x)|\geq |\sup_{x}g(x) - f(x)| = |\sup_{x}g(x) - \inf_{x}f(x)|$. Then, as $f(x),g(x)\in [0,1]$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ one of the two final terms, at least, are greater or equal than $|\inf_{x}f(x) - \inf_{x}g(x)|$. Is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the inequality always holds.

Let $F:=\inf_x f(x)$, $G:=\inf_x g(x)$.
We can
assume w.l.o.g. that $F<G$.

For any $0<\varepsilon<G-F$ there exists a $y$ such that
$$f(y)<F+\varepsilon < G \leq g(y)$$
so
$$\sup_x |f(x)-g(x)| \geq \underbrace{g(y)}_{\geq G} - f(y) \geq G-F - \varepsilon .$$
Letting $\varepsilon\to 0$ shows the claim.